# Komodo edit syntax highlightening

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, komodoedit

I just installed Active state's komodo edit on my Windows. It's running fine but unable to detect syntax errors in php file. Like this code

```
<?php> 
phpinfo() foo[] is my name          
?>
```

There must be a red error highlighted line beneath the error.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should help you this forum thread?

http://community.activestate.com/forum/php-syntax-checking-komodo